# scrollTo() not scrolling after tabs('select',#)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm losing my mind, this is supposed to be simple and I'm sure I've over-complicating it like a jQuery noob. Sigh.

So I have this page that takes #switchto=ac#goto=acemergency hashtags and switches jQuery tabs appropriately, after which it's supposed to go to(scroll to) the desired ID. The problem is that tabs() automatically scrolls back to the top of container and when scrollTo() is called it no longer knows where to scroll. It doesn't scroll at all in other words.

Here's my event handler:

```
jQuery(window).hashchange(function(e) {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
        var instruct = hash.split('#'); //split instructions
        var whichtab = instruct[0].split('='); // split instruction from tab name

        try {
            var whichid = instruct[1].split('='); // split instruction from id name
        }
        catch (err) { /*suppress*/
        }

        if (whichtab[0] == "switchto") {
            switch (whichtab[1]) {
                case 'ac':
                    try {
                        if (whichid[1] != "") {
                            $s.when(targettab(0)).then(targetid(whichid[1]));
                        }
                    } catch (err) {}
                    $s('.tour').tabs('select', 0);
                    break;
                case 'heating':
                    try {
                        if (whichid[1] != "") {
                            $s.when(targettab(1)).then(targetid(whichid[1]));
                        }
                    } catch (err) {}
                    $s('.tour').tabs('select', 1);
                    break;
                case 'plumbing':
                    try {
                        if (whichid[1] != "") {
                            $s.when(targettab(2)).then(targetid(whichid[1]));
                        }
                    } catch (err) {}
                    $s('.tour').tabs('select', 2);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here's my functions:

```
function targetid(givenid) {
    //$s('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $s("#"+givenid).offset().top},'fast');
    $s.scrollTo($s("#" + givenid), 400);
    $s("#" + givenid).delay(500).fadeTo('slow', 0.1, function() {
        $s("#" + givenid).fadeTo('slow', 1);
        console.log('got ' + givenid + ' and scrolled to it');
    });
}

function targettab(giventab) {
    $s('.tour').tabs('select', giventab);
}
```

I tried several ways I've found here on stackoverflow but none of them seems to fix my issue. Any ideas? Is there a way to stop tabs() from scrolling back to the top on tabsselect?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really looked that hard at your code, but don't you really mean scrollTop and not scrollTo? Assuming $s is your jQuery object, what happens when you try:

```
$s("#" + givenid).scrollTop(400);
```

This also assumes that $s("#" + givenid) is the correct selector for the container that you want to scroll.

I could be off here (again, didn't look that hard), but I hope it helps!